# Why this null pointer error is comming?

Tags: android, arrays, nullpointerexception

I was making a list of favorite activity in the android which uses `arraylist`
as a storing place,but when i was triggering the event by the button press,null pointer error is coming. Why is it so...???
Here is the code of my Kinematics activity where the button is being pressed.

```
public class Kinematics extends AppCompatActivity {
private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
private NavigationView navigationView;
private ActionBarDrawerToggle phy_law_toggel;
private Toolbar toolbar;
private WebView webView;
private ScrollView scrollview;
private FloatingActionButton fab;
private ImageButton fav;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final Favouritepage favr = new Favouritepage();
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_kinematics);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.phy_lawtoolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    setTitle(R.string.Kinematics);
    drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.phy_draw);
    navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view_phy);

    phy_law_toggel = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,drawerLayout,R.string.open, R.string.Close);
    drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(phy_law_toggel);
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.phy_lawtoolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    phy_law_toggel.syncState();
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    navigationView.setItemIconTintList(null);
    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.phy_law_web);
    fav = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.fav);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
    final String kine = this.getClass().getSimpleName();
    webView.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(true);
    webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/mathscribe/Kinematics.html");
    fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    scrollview = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scroll);

    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            webView.scrollTo(0, 0);
        }
    });
    fav.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            favr.mfavlist.add(kine);
        }
    });


}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (phy_law_toggel.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}}
```

Here, i am making an object of my FavoritePage class and trying to store the element in the arrayList of FavoritePage.

Here is my FavoritePage class

```
public class Favouritepage extends AppCompatActivity {

public ArrayList<String> mfavlist;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_favouritepage);
    mfavlist = new ArrayList<String>();

}}
```

And here is the XML of kinematics,

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout                                
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/phy_draw"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context="com.example.alpit.formula2.Kinematics">


<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/phy_lawtoolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar.PopupOverlay">


    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>


    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/phy_law_web"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/phy_lawtoolbar"></WebView>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="56dp"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/phy_law_web"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_marginBottom="43dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
        android:src="@drawable/fabss"
        app:backgroundTint="#F57F17">  

</android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/fav"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/phy_law_web"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:src="@drawable/fav" />


</RelativeLayout>


<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view_phy"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:background="#FFAB40"
    app:menu="@menu/navigation_menu"
    app:theme="@style/NavigationTheme" />
```

crashlog

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.example.alpit.formula2, PID: 22744
              java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.util.ArrayList.add(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
                  at com.example.alpit.formula2.Kinematics$2.onClick(Kinematics.java:64)
                  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4802)
                  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:20102)
                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:810)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:189)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5529)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:950)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:745)
```

Comment: please share crash report or logs

Comment: @Henry , I dont think so, i might be lacking some concept though. Do review my code.

Comment: @AlpitAnand Yes, your variables are null, so please debug your own code to see "how to fix it". Many many questions about null variables, yet, no one takes the time to understand how to fix it themselves

Comment: @cricket_007,its been two days, still trying to figure out,I might need another set of eyes to look at my code,still trying though..

Answer (score 1):

Add this line after setContentView in your Kinematic.

```
ArrayList<String> mfavlist = new ArrayList<String>();
```

edit this line of your code

```
fav.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
       mfavlist.add(kine);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply though,but we are adding the name of activities in `FavoriteList`, I want my ArrayList in `FavoriteList`,instead of having arraylist locally in every activity.

Comment: You can not access your arraylist from One Activity to other Activity

Comment: there are 2 ways : pass your arraylist to Kinematic Activity with Intent
OR create Application class & replace an arraylist at there.

Comment: When your Favouritepageactivity finished then your arraylist will be null so its fired NullPointerException

Comment: Okie, thanks i will give a try, but not even by creating a object i can access it..??

Comment: you need to create Application class & initialize your arraylist at there & then after you can access that Arraylist from Anywhere in your application

Comment: https://www.intertech.com/Blog/androids-application-class/
this can help you to create an application class

Comment: Yaah sure, i always do, just let me check if it works

Comment: working my solution ?

Comment: I will soon as return from collage...

Answer (score 0):

> Here is my FavoritePage class

```
public class Favouritepage extends AppCompatActivity {
```

... Meanwhile in your other class...

```
final Favouritepage favr = new Favouritepage();
```

Never **ever** `new` an Activity class (because `onCreate` is never called, therefore the list **is null**)

Basically, I do not think `FavouritePage` should extend Activity at all.

Learn more about POJO classes

```
public class Favouritepage {

    public ArrayList<String> mfavlist = new ArrayList<String>();

    public Favouritepage() { 
        // Empty constructor 
    }
}
```

---

Or, if it needs does need to be an Activity class, you will have to find a different way to "share" that list between activities.

Comment: Still, same null Pointer, thanks for reply though.

Comment: Shouldn't be. Like I said, `onCreate` is never called. In your code, `mfavlist = new ArrayList<String>();` is never ran.